# Firebase Realtime Database equal_to() method gets the whole document instead of the parent only

Tags: python-3.x, firebase-realtime-database, pyrebase

I have this structure:

```
-User:
     -user1:
              -name : cycy
              -email: cycy@test.com
```

What I intend to do is know what parent does the input email contains. for example if my input email is cycy@test.com, I should be able to output "user1". Here is my code:

```
hey = db.child("User").order_by_child("email").equal_to("cycy@test.com").get()
print(hey.val())
```

My problem with this code is that it outputs everything and not the parent "user1" only
`OrderedDict([('user1', {'name: cycy, email: cycy@test.com})])`

How can i modify this so that it only gives the parent "user1"

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Realtime Database queries always give a list of results, as there may be multiple child nodes that match the query. Even when there's only one result, you get a list of that one result. There is no way to change that behavior.

You will have to loop over the results, like shown in the Pyrebase documentation on [handling a list of results](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase#each). Based on that, your code would look something like:

```
for user in hey.each():
    print(user.key())
    print(user.val())
```